# How to use request library to send keys to web page in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I have a website https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx which when visited, I've to enter the '**CP number**' as **16803**, & click on search. After that information of student displays which I need to **scrape**. Can someone please help how to pass the '**CP number**' to request & how to press the '**search**' button using request.

So far I've tried using the class name & id name as well in **param** tag of **request.get()** method.

```
import requests
r=requests.get('https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx',params={'dnn_ctr410_MemberSearch_txtCpNumber':16803})
```

In above code I have tried using param name as:
[Class name & id name]

dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtCpNumber

dnn_ctr410_MemberSearch_txtCpNumber

I don't how to work it & I can't use selenium or mechanise like library, can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I tried, & got it working using this,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

s=requests.Session()

resp=s.get('https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx')
resp

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content,"html5lib")

dictinfo = {i['name']: i.get('value', '') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
dictinfo['dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtCpNumber'] = 16803
dictinfo["__EVENTTARGET"] = 'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$btnSearch'
dictinfo = {k:(None, str(v)) for k,v in dictinfo.items()}

resp = s.post('https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx', files=dictinfo)

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"html5lib")

name=soup2.select_one(".name_head").text
#print(name)

info=[str(i.text).strip() for i in soup2.select(".chart_head")]
#print(info)

detail=[str(i.text).strip() for i in soup2.select(".chart_detail")]
#print(detail)

print("Name : ",name)
data=pd.DataFrame({'Info':info,'Details':detail},columns=['Info', 'Details'])
data
```

Thank you so much to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

[website](https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx) submit button `rendering` `js or ajax request`. You should try automation `selenium` library. it allows you to **scrape** dynamic `rendering request(js or ajax)` page data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx')

reg = browser.find_element_by_name('dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtCpNumber')
reg.send_keys('16803')

sub = browser.find_element_by_class_name('dnnPrimaryAction')
sub.click()

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "rgMasterTable")))

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
table = soup.find("table",{'class':"rgMasterTable"}).find("tr",{'class':"rgRow"})

data = {}
for div in table.find_all("div",{'class':"chart_att"}):
    for div2 in div.find_all("div"):
        _class = div2.get("class")

        if "chart_row" in _class[0]:
            key = None
            value = None
            for td in div2.find_all("td"):
                _class1 = td.get("class")

                if "chart_head" in _class1[0]:
                    key = td.text.strip()
                else:
                    value = td.text.strip()
            if key is not None and value is not None:
                data[key] = value

print(data)
```

O/P:

```
{'Organization': 'RAHUL SHINDE AND COMPANY', 'Designation': 'COMPANY SECRETARIES (*)', 'Membership Number': 'A32412', 'CP Number': '16803', 'Benevolent Member': 'No', 'Address': '25/26, 3RD FLOOR, PAREERA BUILDING NAVJEEVAN WADI, KALBADEVI POST DHOBI TALAV, MARINE LINES', 'City': 'MUMBAI', 'Phone': '', 'Email': 'jurisrahul@gmail.com', 'Mobile': '8369683685'}
```

where `'/usr/bin/chromedriver'` selenium web driver path.

**Download selenium web driver for chrome browser:**

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

**Install web driver for chrome browser:**

https://christopher.su/2015/selenium-chromedriver-ubuntu/

**Selenium tutorial:**

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Thank  you so much Bharat, but I can't use selenium, I can use only REQUEST & BS4 library. Anyways I finally tried out & it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve your problem and I was able to fetch the member details according to CP number using Curl command 
The curl command which worked is ::

```
curl 'https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36' -H 'Origin: https://www.icsi.in' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3' -H 'Referer: https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'Cookie: .ASPXANONYMOUS=Yi-3rxhT1QEkAAAAN2Y1ZGE1ZDQtN2FjOC00NmJlLWFmNzEtMTRmYmNjZThiMzAz0; language=en-US; __utma=268070294.1401783362.1559839356.1559839356.1559839356.1; __utmc=268070294; __utmz=268070294.1559839356.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmt=1; __utmb=268070294.9.10.1559839356' --data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="StylesheetManager_TSSM"\r\n\r\n;Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2011.3.1115.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4:en-US:f0ea1c34-9d2c-42a1-84c3-49717427a593:9e1572d6:e25b4b77\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="ScriptManager_TSM"\r\n\r\n;;System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:en:eb198dbd-2212-44f6-bb15-882bde414f00:ea597d4b:b25378d2;Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2011.3.1115.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4:en:f0ea1c34-9d2c-42a1-84c3-49717427a593:16e4e7cd:58366029\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTTARGET"\r\n\r\ndnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$btnSearch\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTARGUMENT"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="__VIEWSTATE"\r\n\r\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\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"\r\n\r\n6A295697\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTVALIDATION"\r\n\r\n1eO5OePdCTECUOCaykvLo65wq/pTry9rKOEYyreRsnnxiTpBbtYAIPUG+bVt2l4zVxPCliqCPAmRPBbYNUAFvgSy+x54jvq73espjGpQssT1TlOP1J3StMO0MDMiQIF/6Cw/jckVtXWV0b6fP7W2qnEzvALQXz6YwtS2urQiOZ+4nHaMevnrjENuHKlgR4D1zA6U+XAhdvds4fwO2pcNHL8nKr/Sog6efTRV40jwCPaJKR0CT5StHsnekIc/9DZY8RsxcF61tgN/HnjkUX6Wu8GlkrgVy6rAoqfteSUduE6MizWzu6DTcZhRYjXasjnDjjnWMBAba8Id8YiqJMIrPEuiU0w6tk1Pf034om2/uXIr1wFD5QUV8yC09x8Z+g+NHU1u7yH2AF/nuetY2PvNO6WSfsD7r1YGL47ZK9ADu/BA7pT+GMIq7Y7oc0kcbszAh2Tuw3YOouV6+LE+zoypa//x8vubNKsBdhZWcA==\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dnn$ctlHeader$dnnSearch$Search"\r\n\r\nSiteRadioButton\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dnn$ctlHeader$dnnSearch$txtSearch"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtFirstName"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtLastName"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$ddlMemberType"\r\n\r\n0\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtMembershipNumber"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtCpNumber"\r\n\r\n16803\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtCity"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtOrganisation"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtAddress2"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtAddress3"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtEmail"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dnn_ctr410_MemberSearch_grdMembers_ClientState"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="ScrollTop"\r\n\r\n329\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="__dnnVariable"\r\n\r\n{"__scdoff":"1","__dnn_pageload":"__dnn_setScrollTop();"}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryjACWRjNNdWvIyQAt--\r\n' --compressed
```

If you are still unable to get the desired result through the requests module then you can automate the curl request and get the work done what the requests will do for you.
If you are going to try this method then you just have to change the "CpNumber" attribute value and for doing that you can search for that attribute in the curl request.
Hope this will work out for you.

Comment: Thank you so much Prateek, well it's hard unterstand your code. So I did some research & did managed to convert CURL code into Python. But unfortunately, after executing python code, it didn't showed the ouput or the required result.

Comment: I had tried to convert that curl into python requests using website https://curl.trillworks.com but didn't get expected result. But, You can use the subprocess module and run that curl command as a process.@David Welcome, If you liked the efforts then Upvote :)

Comment: Well thanks Prateek, but as I said I did the same to convert the CURL to request. But didn't found result. And I'm restricted to use only request & beautifulsoup library to complete this task.