# How to select value from dropdown item using requests in Python 3?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request, python-requests

I want to scrape data from the website https://xlnindia.gov.in/frm_G_Cold_S_Query.aspx. I have to select the **State** as **Delhi**, **District** as **Adarsh Nagar (4)** & click on **Search** button, and scrape all the information.

So far I tried using the given below code as

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Error was coming as '**HTTPS 443 SSL**', which I ressolved using '**verify = False**

```
resp = requests.get('https://xlnindia.gov.in/frm_G_Cold_S_Query.aspx',verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")

dictinfo = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
dictinfo['ddlState']='Delhi'
dictinfo['ddldistrict']='Adarsh Nagar (4)'
dictinfo['__EVENTTARGET']='btnSearch'
dictinfo = {k:(None,str(v)) for k,v in dictinfo.items()}
r=requests.post('https://xlnindia.gov.in/frm_G_Cold_S_Query.aspx',verify=False,files=dictinfo)
r
```

> Error: Response [500]

soup2

> Error:
>   
>    
>     
>    
>   Invalid postback or callback
>   argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages
>   enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes,
>   this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events
>   originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If
>   the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

Can someone please help me to scrape it or get it done.

(*I can only use **REQUEST** & **BEAUTIFULSOUP** library, no SELENIUM, MECHANIZE,etc. libraries.* )

Comment: why are you trying to send the dict as a file?

Comment: you probably also need some headers

Comment: Also `ddlState` corresponds to `'DL'` when using the browser, check your inputs again

Comment: @SuperStew - Hi Stew, actually I'm new to Requests library, I usually prefer Selenium in such scenarios. I found from a link [how to pass parameter](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls).  I tried using it, but it doesn't seems working. I saw javascript post method when STATE is selected & found "ddlState" variable is used so I used that variable as a dict parameter to post method of requests library.

Comment: Check that you don't need to do at least two separate POST requests as I see an initial POST request immediately after selecting Delhi. If so, use Session to carry over cookies.. from first POST.

Comment: @QHarr - Thanks QHarr, I tried to do post twice but "RESPONSE 500" error is showing it seems that get or post method is not accepting HTTPS properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the script below to get the tabular results meant to be populated choosing two dropdown items as you stated above from that webpage. Turn out that you have to make two subsequent post requests to populate the results.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

url = 'https://xlnindia.gov.in/frm_G_Cold_S_Query.aspx'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0'
    resp = s.get(url,verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")

    dictinfo = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    dictinfo['ddlState'] = 'DL'

    res = s.post(url,data=dictinfo)
    soup_obj = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup_obj.select('input[name]')}
    payload['ddldistrict'] = 'ADN'

    r = s.post(url,data=payload)
    sauce = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for items in sauce.select("#dgDisplay tr"):
        data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("td")]
        print(data)
```

Output you may see in the console like:

```
['Firm Name', 'City', 'Licences', 'Reg. Pharmacists / Comp. Person']
['A ONE MEDICOS', 'DELHI-251/1, GALI NO.1, KH, NO, 739/251/1, NEAR HIMACHAL BHAWAN,SARAI PIPAL THALA, VILLAGE AZAD PUR,', 'R - 2', 'virender kumar, DPH, [22295-17/10/2013]']
['AAROGYAM', 'DELHI-PVT. SHOP NO. 1, GF, 121,VILLAGE BHAROLA', 'R - 2', 'avinesh bhadoriya, DPH, [27033-]']
['ABCO INDIA', 'DELHI-SHOP NO-452/22,BHUSHAN BHAWAN RING ROAD,FLYOVER AZAD PUR', 'W - 2', 'sanjay dubey , SSC, [C-P-03/01/1997]']
['ADARSH MEDICOS', 'DELHI-NORTHERN SIDE B-107, GALI NO. 1,,MAJLIS PARK, VILLAGE BHAROLA,', 'R - 2', 'dilip kumar, BPH, [28036-11/01/2018]']
```

Comment: Aren't you specifying SEARCH button in payload dict, though output is coming but still as in webpage, output table shows after clicking on Search button only so...

Comment: If you print payload, you can see that this `'btnSearch': 'Search'` is already there. You don't need to specify it explicitly. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks SIM, & one last question, I replaced the 'data' parameter with 'files' in the request method of your code. Then it doesn't show output, but if 'data' parameter is used which you did in your code, it shows. As far as I know both are used for accepting dictionary parameter. Then, how 'files' parameter not working...

Comment: Nope you can't do that. When using `get` requests you should use `params=anything` and when you go for `post` requests, it should be `data=anything`. `anything` means any name you can use.

Comment: Actually there is answer in the link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56481600/how-to-use-request-library-to-send-keys-to-web-page-in-python/56495325#56495325) similar to this question, in which I've used 'files' parameter & it was working.

Comment: Check out this ***[link](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)*** for the clarity.